# Adding class based on element height - jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm having difficulty getting this scrip to work properly:

```
$(window).(function(){
var maxHeight = 330;
if  (maxHeight < 331)
$('.ui-lightbox-mid').addClass('addScroll');
else 
$('.ui-lightbox-mid').removeClass('addScroll'); 
});
```

What I'm trying to do is confine a lightbox to 330px tall without adding a scrollbar all the time. I'm adding a class ('addScroll' //which is just overflow-y:scroll css wise) when the content is larger than 330px in order to add scrolling to the lightbox.

Can anyone help?

thanks
Joe

Comment: document.ready or window.load should do the trick

Comment: You'll also need to find the height of the lightbox element. Right now your logic will always add the `addScroll` class

Answer (score 3):

`$(window).function(){ .. })` is not proper structure. Instead of it use:

`$(window).load(function() { .. })`

But in proper ***jQuery*** way:

`$(document).ready(function() { .. })`.

**OR**

`$(function() { .. })`

***Full Code***

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var maxHeight = 330,
        lightbox = $('.ui-lightbox-mid'), // caching reference
        lightboxHeight = lightbox.height(); // get the current height
                                            // of lightbox, to compare
                                            // with maxHeight

    if ( maxHeight < lightboxHeight ) 
       lightbox.addClass('addScroll');
    else 
       lightbox.removeClass('addScroll');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
$(window).(function(){
```

to:

```
$(window).load(function(){
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should wait until to document-ready event was triggered, before it doesn't make sense to retrieve the height anyhow. This can be done with `$(document).ready(function() { ... })`